# Wait for click event inside a for loop - similar to prompt()

Tags: javascript, for-loop, prompt

This might not have the greatest title. I'm trying to understand call back functions, and I was wondering how replacing prompt() in the following code could be achieved, without losing the for loop?

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  let x = prompt("Input an integer");
  // store input into an array
}
```

I've tried something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i<4; i++){
  let x = document.getElementById("someId");
  x.addEventListener("click", rcvInput(function(i){
    if(i == 3){
      x.removeEventListener("click", rcvInput)
    }
  }));
}
function rcvInput(callback){
  //store input into an array
  callback();
}
```

I know this can be done without the for loop, I'm more curious if callbacks could be able to pause the loop and wait for input?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do, but I strongly suspect you're really overthinking it.  Take a step back, what's the goal here?  It looks like you're just trying to get a value from an input when the user clicks a button.  So what's the purpose of a loop or callback or any of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what your end goal is, I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it. But for the sake of doing that:

You can create a method that returns a promise that resolves when a click happens. Then you can use `async`/`await` to do what you need.

By using a `Promise` and `await`ing on it, you can technically "pause" your `for` loop until something happens. In this case, a click.

Remember the method that encloses the `for` loop has to be `async`.

```js
function getClick() {
  return new Promise(acc => {
    function handleClick() {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
      acc();
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  });
}


async function main() {
  for (let i=0;i<4;i++) {
    console.log("waiting for a click", i);
    await getClick();
    console.log("click received", i);
  }
  console.log("done");
}

main();
```

Try it in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ADzvLiJmn38Mmp0ipu2u?p=preview).

Comment: thanks Amir - just to understand... the async method pauses the for loop, and waits for the getClick() to return void?

Comment: `getClick` returns a promise. `await` waits for that promise to resolve. In this example, the promise resolves to void, but technically, you can resolve it to anything you want, like `acc('the thing you want')`. Then you'll have that resolved value as a result of `await`. `const resolvedValue = await getClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

To acheieve:

```
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
  let x = prompt("Input an integer"); // WAIT FOR PROMPT
  // ...
  // LOOP CODE AFTER PROMPT
}
```

you can use recursion:

```
function promptLoop(count){
    let x =  prompt("Input an integer");
    // ...
    // LOOP CODE AFTER PROMPT
    if (count > 0) promptLoop(count - 1)
}
```

and use it like so:

```
promptLoop(4);
```

---

Your second scenario is different, and can be adapted like so:

```
function loop(count, method) {
    if (count > 0) method(() => loop(count - 1, method), count);
}
```

Your function would then take a next callback, like so:

```
function toBeLooped(next){
    // do stuff
    next() // continues loop 
}

loop(3, toBeLooped);
```