# Why is this loop executing without me clicking any button?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom-events

I am trying to build a rock paper scissors game and I’m having a hard time with loops and events in JS. When I run this script, it counts `userChoice` as `undefined`. Why is the loop not waiting till I click any button?

This is part of the oddin project: Revisiting Rock Paper Scissors - Foundations Course

```js
// Setting the game score to 0.
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');

// Main game function.
function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    /* Play the game 5 rounds. */
    let values = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; /* The possibilities the computer can choose. */
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length); /* I use the random built-in function to randomly pick a value from the array. */

    function getComputerChoice() { /* Function for the computer choice. */
      return values[index];
    }

    let computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    let userChoice

    rock.addEventListener("click", function() {
      userChoice = 'rock';
    });
    paper.addEventListener("click", function() {
      userChoice = 'paper';
    });
    scissors.addEventListener("click", function() {
      userChoice = 'scissors';
    });

    function roundOfGame(userChoice, computerChoice) {
      if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return ("It is a tie");
      } else if ((userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissor") || (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice == "rock") || (userChoice === "scissor" && computerChoice === "paper")) {
        userScore = userScore += 1;
        
        return (`Player wins! ${userChoice} beats ${computerChoice}. User score = ${userScore} and computer score = ${computerScore}`)
      } else {
        computerScore = computerScore += 1;
        
        return (`Computer wins! ${computerChoice} beats ${userChoice}. User score = ${userScore} and computer score = ${computerScore}`)
      }
    }

    console.log(roundOfGame(userChoice, computerChoice));
  }
}

game()
```

Comment: Your "\* Play the game 5 rounds \*"? loop? Because it's the first thing called within `game()` and you call `game()` right after it's defined. It's not tied to an event listener.

Comment: *"why is the loop not waiting till i click any button?"* - On the very last line of code shown you are immediately executing your `game()` function.  Did you not mean to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for click event inside a for loop - similar to prompt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916739/wait-for-click-event-inside-a-for-loop-similar-to-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

It's not how you usually handle user events in JavaScript. `addEventListener` takes a callback instead of returning for a reason. It's a non-blocking operation and by default everything after `addEventListener` will run immediately

To make it work as you want you can create a function like this:

```
function waitForClick(options) {
  return new Promise(r => {
    const listeners = []
    options.forEach(option => {
      const waitFor = () => {
        r(option.value)
        listeners.forEach(listener => {
          listener.element.removeEventListener('click', listener.fn)
        })
      }
      option.element.addEventListener('click', waitFor)
      listeners.push({ element: option.element, fn: waitFor })
    })
  })
}
```

and than await for it:

```
const userChoice = await waitForClick([{
    element: rock,
    value: 'rock'
  },
  {
    element: paper,
    value: 'paper'
  },
  {
    element: scissors,
    value: 'scissors'
  },
])
```

```js
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');

async function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let values = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);

    function getComputerChoice() {
      return values[index];
    }

    let computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

    const userChoice = await waitForClick([{
        element: rock,
        value: 'rock'
      },
      {
        element: paper,
        value: 'paper'
      },
      {
        element: scissors,
        value: 'scissors'
      },
    ])

    console.log('player', userChoice, 'computer', computerChoice)

    function roundOfGame(userChoice, computerChoice) {
      if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        return ("It is a tie");
      } else if ((userChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissors") || (userChoice === "paper" && computerChoice == "rock") || (userChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "paper")) {
        userScore = userScore += 1;

        return (`Player wins! ${userChoice} beats ${computerChoice}. User score = ${userScore} and computer score = ${computerScore}`)
      } else {
        computerScore = computerScore += 1;

        return (`Computer wins! ${computerChoice} beats ${userChoice}. User score = ${userScore} and computer score = ${computerScore}`)
      }
    }

    console.log(roundOfGame(userChoice, computerChoice));
  }
}

game()

function waitForClick(options) {
  return new Promise(r => {
    const listeners = []
    options.forEach(option => {
      const waitFor = () => {
        r(option.value)
        listeners.forEach(listener => {
          listener.element.removeEventListener('click', listener.fn)
        })
      }
      option.element.addEventListener('click', waitFor)
      listeners.push({
        element: option.element,
        fn: waitFor
      })
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="rock">rock</button>
<button class="paper">paper</button>
<button class="scissors">scissors</button>
```

Comment: If you run the code, the results displayed are not following the game rules, do you know why?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I will fix it

Comment: There was a typo in `scissors` inside the if statement. Also, we have to clear all event listeners after each click hence changes

Comment: Just saw the scissors typo, what an idiot i am. Thanks Konrad!